# Centering a box inside square brackets in equation

Tags: equations

I am trying to write the notation of a matrix transformation with respect to two bases in linear algebra. I am having troubles centering a box within my square brackets. Using the code below I almost get the desired result, but the box isn't centering within the brackets.

```
\begin{align*}
    _{\mathcal{E}} [{\framebox{}}]_{\mathcal{V}} =
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \lvert & \lvert & & \lvert \\
            \bm{v}_1 &\bm{v}_2 & \dots & \bm{v}_n \\
            \lvert & \lvert & & \lvert
        \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Any help with moving the box up a bit would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dear user, thank you for the trust for the green tick but it was probably Steven's first. I kindly ask you, because my response is not the best to give the green tick to either Steven or egreg. I hope for your understanding. Greetings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}` to center something vertically about the math axis.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    _{\mathcal{E}} [\vcenter{\hbox{{\framebox{}}}}]_{\mathcal{V}} =
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \lvert & \lvert & & \lvert \\
            \bm{v}_1 &\bm{v}_2 & \dots & \bm{v}_n \\
            \lvert & \lvert & & \lvert
        \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\bases}[2]{{}_{\mathcal{#1}}[{\mathop\square}]_{\mathcal{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\bases{E}{F}
\]

\end{document}
```

When `\mathop` acts on a single symbol, it will vertically center it with respect to the formula axis, just like brackets do.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `tensor` package to align the calligraphic symbols in subscript mode. The use of `\newcommand: \nsquare` with the `-.7pt` guarantees me, among other things, to center the square inside the square brackets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tensor,bm}
\newcommand{\nsquare}[1][-.7pt]{
  \mathrel{\raisebox{#1}{$\square$}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \tensor[_{\mathcal{E}}]{[\nsquare]}{_{\mathcal{V}}} =
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \lvert & \lvert & & \lvert \\
            \bm{v}_1 &\bm{v}_2 & \dots & \bm{v}_n \\
            \lvert & \lvert & & \lvert
        \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Related to the my question: [Tensor package with the calligraphic characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591314/tensor-package-with-the-calligraphic-characters)