# Tensor package with the calligraphic characters

Tags: errors, amssymb, calligraphy, tensor

I have seen the documentation of `tensor` [package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tensor). It is true that are necessary only the indices....but is it possible to use with this package the calligraphic characters like this MWE?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}
$\tensor[_\mathcal{A}]{C}{_\mathcal{B}}$
\end{document}
```

With this MWE, for example, I have of the mistakes.

```
! Package tensor Error: Sub/Superscript items out of order on input line 6, 
(tensor)                some index tokens may now have been lost.

See the tensor package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.6     $\tensor[_\mathcal{A}]{C}{_\mathcal{B}}
                                               $
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use braces.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}
$\tensor[_{\mathcal{A}}]{C}{_{\mathcal{B}}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have done a trivial mistake....thank you very very very much.